# Web Browser / slow computer - "Stop running this script?"

Tags: windows, browser, javascript

*(Not my computer, a friend's who I will call Beth for ease of reading, so will provide what I can)*

Computer displays this pop up on start up. Computer is very slow, sometimes unresponsive:

[image: photo of pop up]

Things to note:

- Happens on start up before Beth has used computer in any way (1 in 3 startups on average, not every time).
- Computer has just had a factory reset completed by Beth, I have installed AVG, Libre Office and Chrome (via USB downloaded on my own computer). Nothing else has been added by either party.
- Scanned computer using AVG, nothing was found.
- No web browsers are running at the time this pop up appears. None are set to start on startup.
- IE is currently the only web browser that has been used, it was pointed to google.com homepage once. No other websites have been visited.
- This started to happen before the factory reset, Beth not being great with computers thought FR was the answer to get rid of it.

Unfortunately I was not able to replicate the pop when I had it, hence the photo.

I have Googled this issue the best I can, but cannot find any replication of this. There are similar issues, but they all seem to occur when a web browser is running or due to coders incorrectly programming javascript - neither of these is this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Something is running at startup and connecting to internet. Run the command `SHELL:STARTUP` and check what is there. Also run `msconfig.exe`. The tab called  *Startup* will give you the list of services  running at start.

Comment: OK thank you @jcbermu, as soon as I can I will have a look and see what I can find using your advice.